# Specific problems with the quadrupole formulation of gravitational radiation

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves

the quadrupole formula has some counterintuitive consequences, when analysing the power output averaged over a period

$$ P = \langle \frac{d^3 Q_{ij}}{dt^3} \frac{d^3 Q_{ij}}{dt^3} \rangle $$

Specifically, if two separated sources are considered inside the radiation zone, $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$, and assume that each orbit around separate centers $C_1$ and $C_2$ by a length $R$, the quadrupole moment of the pair is going to be (around the common center $C_1 + \frac{R}{2} = C_2 - \frac{R}{2}$)

$$ \int ( \rho_1(x) + \rho_2(x) ) x^j x^k d^3x = \int \rho_1(x) (x_1 - \frac{R}{2})^j (x_1 - \frac{R}{2})^k d^3x + \int \rho_2(x) (x_2 + \frac{R}{2})^j (x_2 + \frac{R}{2})^k d^3x = \int \rho_1(x) x_1^j x_1^k d^3x - \frac{R^j}{2} \int \rho_1(x) x_1^k d^3x - \frac{R^k}{2} \int \rho_1(x) x_1^j d^3x
 + \int \rho_2(x) x_2^j x_2^k d^3x + \frac{R^j}{2} \int \rho_2(x) x_2^k d^3x + \frac{R^k}{2} \int \rho_2(x) x_2^j d^3x$$

$$ = \int \rho_1(x) x_1^j x_1^k d^3x + \int \rho_2(x) x_2^j x_2^k d^3x + \frac{R^j}{2}( \int \rho_2(x) x_2^k d^3x - \int \rho_1(x) x_1^k d^3x ) + \frac{R^k}{2}( \int \rho_2(x) x_2^j d^3x - \int \rho_1(x) x_1^j d^3x )$$

plus some other terms that are constant over time that are not needed

However, the terms $\frac{R^k}{2} \int \rho_c(x) x_c^j d^3x$ will have nonzero third time derivatives in general, so they will contribute to the overall power, even though they depend on an arbitrary choice of a center over which the quadrupole moments are calculated?

What is wrong with this expression, and how to obtain a power output from the quadrupolar moment that doesn't depend over what origin of coordinates is chosen for the calculation?

Answer (score 1):

The remaining terms are all mass dipoles. If linear momentum is conserved on each center, then the mass dipoles will be constant:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int \rho(x)x^k \, d^3 x = \int \rho(x) v^k d^3 x $$

which is the total linear momentum. If the system doesn't receive any linear momentum to first order, its second and third derivatives will be all zero.